# Customize RPC Provider calling on-chain view

Tags: rpc

Is there any abstraction to call contract on-chain views at a given block level?

And regardless of that, if I want to customize the rpc provider before calling the view, how can I do that? Can someone point me to a generic example or documentation? Or if not existing give a short example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any abstraction to call contract on-chain views at a given block level?

Yes, Octez has both a node RPC (/helpers/scripts/run_script_view) and a client command (`octez-client run view`) to do this.

> if I want to customize the rpc provider before calling the view

Please explain more precisely what you mean by this. What do you want to customize?